# Google Chrome - deceptive sites

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, security-warning

I have a free third level domain registered here https://www.dnsexit.com/domains/free-second-level-domains/ to test virtual machine. This domains DNS directs to my virtual server which is under my control (I hope so). I have a ssl certificates for all sites but one of them which is [Next Cloud application](https://nextcloud.com/) shows me a warning about deceptive site. I don't understand what it means. Communication is encrypted Next Cloud is commonly used application so what is the problem? Also all the scripts on the site comes from my server. No third party scripts.

Here is the screenshot [image]

Comment: I would imagine it likely has to do with the reputation of the higher level domain itself.  If users have reported malicious files or Google has detected malicious behavior.  I would imagine Google Safe Browsing has something to do with it.  If you trust the domain then you can consider it a false positive.  If you want other people not to get the warning that is an entirely different problem likely only solved by changing your configuration entirely.

Comment: Yes it is only for test purpose. No other users are involved.

Comment: Is it the following bug? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068202

Comment: Yes it seems it the same problem including disabled links.